# Is $N=2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n-1}}+2^{2^{n-2}}+2^{2^{n-3}} + \ldots+ 2^{2^3}+2^{2^2}+n$ is always composite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Is number of the following form is always composite:

$$N=2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n-1}}+2^{2^{n-2}}+2^{2^{n-3}} + . . . 2^{2^3}+2^{2^2}+n$$

I found similar question for $2^{2^n}+5$ .

My attempt:
We can rewrite N as :

$$N=2^{2^n}+1+2^{2^{n-1}}+1+2^{2^{n-2}}+1+2^{2^{n-3}}+1 + . . . 2^{2^3}+1+2^{2^2}+1$$

So we have a sum of n Fermat numbers. we may write:

$2^{2a}+1=(3-1)^{2a}+1=3k+2$

Therefore the sum each three numbers will be divisible by 3, hence for N being a primes, n must not be divisible by 3. Also n must not be divisible by 2 that means n must be divisible by 6. I checked this up to $n=6$ .

$2^{2^n}≡6 \mod (10)$

So:

$2^{2^n}+1≡7 \mod (10)$:

$2^{2^2}+1+2^{2^3}+1+2^{2^4}+1=165811≡1 \mod(10)$

$2^{2^2}+1+2^{2^3}+1+2^{2^4}+1+2^{2^5}+1≡8 \mod(10)$

$2^{2^2}+1+2^{2^3}+1+2^{2^4}+1+2^{2^5}+1+2^{2^6}+1≡5 \mod(10)$

$2^{2^2}+1+2^{2^3}+1+2^{2^4}+1+2^{2^5}+1+2^{2^6}+1+2^{2^7}+1≡2 \mod(10)$

$2^{2^2}+1+2^{2^3}+1+2^{2^4}+1+2^{2^5}+1+2^{2^6}+1+2^{2^7}+2^{2^8}+1≡9 \mod(10)$

The odd numbers which may appear as last digit are 1, 3, 7 and 9 and  the period of repeating of these numbers  as the last digit is 10. I could not check for n=8. My answer to this question is no.We can write:

$\displaystyle{\Sigma}^n_{i=1}(2^{2^n}+n)≡2n \mod (3)≡-n\ mod (3)= 3m-n$

Which is  a linear equivalent and indicates N may be a prime.

Comment: Trivially, if n is even, N also must be even

Comment: It is not prime for $n$ up to $16$.

Comment: For $n=7$ the smallest prime divisor is $43$, so it is unlikely you will find a simple proof utilizing small primes. You can prove some subclasses though, for $n=6k-1$ we have $3 \mid N$, for $n=10k+3$ we have $5 \mid N$, for $n=14k-1$ we have $7 \mid N$, and so on.

Comment: The growth rate of this sequence is enormous. Considering Servaes' comment, chances to find a prime of this form are extremely small. $2^{2^n}+5$ is however always divisible by $3$ , except for $n=0$ , so the only prime of this form is $7$.